# segue on destination view controller not working after programmatically going to destination view controller

Tags: ios

segues not working after going to destination view controller (which is in storyboard )programmatically from a button click of view controller (which is not in storyboard)

```
- (IBAction)OK:(id)sender {  
    UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    mainViewController *controller = (mainViewController *)[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainViewController"];
    [controller setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Where is the segue in this? Also, what is the specific problem? What are the log messages? crash?

Comment: after going to destination view controller when i click button on it it is not performing segue to different view controller and does notting when button is clicked

Comment: Okay, so please add details about the different view controller, the segue, and how you are trying to execute that segue...

Answer (score 0):

Okey, if i am not wrong, i think , the button click segue is using navigationcontroller , if so , watch your custom segue ,

**[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];**

you are making an model segue, so your navigation controller will be unknown after the segue is done.

Comment: There is no need to use txt speak. Please use the full words for "you" "are" and "your".